# How do I add a value from a callback into a new element with setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron, setattribute

I need to add the value of a callback into my setAttribute. How do I do that?

This value is necessary to get data out of a table at a later moment.

This is the code:

```
row.forEach(function(row) {
         var subchapname = document.createElement("div");
         subchapname.setAttribute("id", "subchaptertitle");
         subchapname.setAttribute("subid", '"+row+"');
         subchapname.setAttribute("onclick","{ alert('You are not going to believe this!') } ");
         subchapname.textContent = row.subname;
         rows.appendChild(subchapname);
```

Basically, this means: 
callback = row

This callback needs to be added to `subchapname.setAttribute("subid", '"+row+"');`

Is this possible?

This is the actual result:

````
<div id="subchaptertitle" subid="&quot;+row+&quot;" onclick="{ alert('You are not going to believe this!') } ">bos in brand</div>```
````

Comment: What value do you want the "subid" attribute to contain eventually? The row callback doesn't actually return a value, it just sets a bunch of attributes and then appends a div with some text.

Comment: Thx for your response :) I actually need the id (which I called subid) from that row. And that row comes from a sqlite-database this way: ```db.all("SELECT subname FROM chaptree WHERE (chapname='" + chapname + "') ORDER BY suborder", function(err,row)```

Comment: You should just be able to do `subchapname.setAttribute("subid", row)` or `subchapname.setAttribute("subid", row.someProperty)` What kind of data structure does `row` have? Can you console log it and update the question?

Answer (score 0):

subid is not attribute to store data in it, so you can not add a attribute like this to a html-tag and fill it with a value (Of course writing a string into it, would work, but is this what you need?). But you can add datasets if you use html5. So use this solution to store your rows-value in the dataset-property of subid.
If row is a object and you want to see the the stringified value of the Object use JSON.stringify before storing it in the dataset

```
row.forEach(function(row) {
  var subchapname = document.createElement("div");
  subchapname.setAttribute("id", "subchaptertitle");
  subchapname.dataset.subid = row;
  // subchapname.dataset.subid = JSON.stringify(row);
  subchapname.setAttribute("onclick","{ alert('You are not going to believe this!') } ");
  subchapname.textContent = row.subname;
  rows.appendChild(subchapname);
});
```

Your Element should now look like this:

```
<div id="subchaptertitle" onclick="{ alert('You are not going to believe this!') } " data-subid="[object Object]"></div>
```

Or if you used JSON.stringify:

```
<div id="subchaptertitle" onclick="{ alert('You are not going to believe this!') } " data-subid="what ever row is as a string"></div>
```

To log the value to the console, (after you added the tag to the DOM) do something like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('subchaptertitle').dataset.subid);
```

In case you used JSON.stringify, now use something like this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('subchaptertitle').dataset.subid));
```

Comment: Thanks for your absolutely brilliant help! I am still learning to program in JavaScript and i didn't know about the dataset property. Your solution and explanation helped me very much! I can now use the values in the dataset to make other calls. Again, thank you very much for your help!!